# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object in a class

Tags: unit-test

Can any one help me out with this error

```
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.CampaignMemberFunctions.UpdateNewToEnterpriseDB: line 12, column 1 Class.TestCampaignMemberFunctions.TestCreationDate: line 58, column 1
```

The line #12 in Class is :

```
if(ld.CreatedDate.addHours(6) > DateTime.Now()) cm.New_to_EnterpriseDB__c = true;
```

The line #58 in TestClass is :

```
CampaignMemberFunctions.UpdateNewToEnterpriseDB(mc1,ld);
```

When i comment line #58 in TestClass the system throws another error as

```
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed
    Class.TestCampaignMemberFunctions.TestCreationDate: line 56, column 1
    the line is System.assert(mc1res.New_to_EnterpriseDB__c);
```

Class :

```
public class CampaignMemberFunctions {
 public static void UpdateNewToEnterpriseDB(CampaignMember cm, Lead ld)
    {
         if(ld.CreatedDate.addHours(6) > DateTime.Now()) cm.New_to_EnterpriseDB__c = true;
    }
  public static Boolean SyncStatus(CampaignMember cm, Lead ld, Contact ct, Map<String, CMStatusSettings__c> statusmap)
    {
        Boolean result = true;
        String newvalue;

        if(ct!= null)
        {
            if(statusmap.containsKey(cm.Response_Status__c))
            {
                newvalue = statusmap.get(cm.Response_Status__c).StatusMapping__c;
                if(newvalue == ct.Status__c)
                {
                    result = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    ct.Status__c = newvalue;
                }
            } else if(cm.Response_Status__c == 'Disqualified' || 
                        cm.Response_Status__c == 'Qualified - New Opportunity' ||
                        cm.Response_Status__c == 'Closed - Converted' )
            {
                newvalue = 'Closed - ' + ct.Account.Customer_Status__c + ' Account';
                if(ct.Status__c == newvalue)
                {
                    result = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    ct.Status__c = newvalue;
                }
                if(cm.Response_Status__c == 'Disqualified')
                {   // Set nuture time on disqualified status
                    Date newtimeout = Date.today().addDays((CMScoreEngine__c.getInstance('Default').NurtureTimeoutDays__c).intValue());
                    if(ct.Admin_Nurture_Timeout__c != newtimeout || ct.Lead_Score__c !=0 || ct.Campaign_Score__c !=0) result = true;
                    ct.Admin_Nurture_Timeout__c = newtimeout;
                    ct.Lead_Score__c = 0; 
                    ct.Campaign_Score__c = 0;   // Probably aren't using this one
                }
            } else
            {
                result = false;
            }       
      }
      else if(ld!=null)
        {
            if(statusmap.containsKey(cm.Response_Status__c))
            {
                newvalue = statusmap.get(cm.Response_Status__c).StatusMapping__c;
                if(newvalue==ld.Status)
                {
                    result = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    ld.Status = newvalue;
                }
            } else if(cm.Response_Status__c == 'Disqualified')
            {
                if(ld.Status=='Disqualified' && ld.Disqaulified_Reason__c == cm.Disqualified_Reason__c)
                {
                    result = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    ld.Status = 'Disqualified';
                    ld.Disqaulified_Reason__c = cm.Disqualified_Reason__c;
                    System.Debug('Disqualified reason being set to: ' + cm.Disqualified_Reason__c);
                }
            } else
            {
                result = false;
            }
         } 
        return(result);

    }
   public static void SyncAfterConversion(Map<Id,Lead> convertedleads, Map<Id, Opportunity>convertedops, Map<Id, CampaignMember> possiblecms) 
    {
        for(Lead ld: convertedleads.values())
        {
            // Grab the campaign member - this must be correct by original query
             CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember();

             System.debug('@@@@@possiblecms.get(ld.admin_CMSourceId__c)'+possiblecms.get(ld.admin_CMSourceId__c));
             cm = possiblecms.get(ld.admin_CMSourceId__c);
             System.debug('@@@@@cm '+cm );
           if(cm!=null)
           {  
            // We know this lead is converted. Let's get the opportunity.             
            if(ld.ConvertedOpportunityId != null)
            {
                Opportunity opp = convertedops.get(ld.ConvertedOpportunityId);
                opp.PMM_stage__c = cm.PMM_Stage__c;
                opp.Product_Interest__c = cm.Product_Interest__c;
                opp.Buyer__c = cm.Buyer__c;
                opp.New_to_EnterpriseDB__c = cm.New_to_EnterpriseDB__c;
                opp.Problem_to_Solve__c = cm.Problem_to_Solve__c;
                opp.Any_OSS_in_current_stack__c = cm.Any_OSS_in_current_stack__c;
                opp.Total_of_Databases_in_your_Org__c = cm.Total_of_Databases_in_your_Org__c;
                opp.Primary_Database__c = cm.Primary_Database__c;
                opp.of_Postgres_Database_Servers__c = cm.of_Postgres_Database_Servers__c;
                opp.Just_learning_about_EnterpriseDB__c = cm.Just_learning_about_EnterpriseDB__c;
                opp.Project_Requires_a_Net_New_DB__c = cm.Project_Requires_a_Net_New_DB__c;
                opp.Timeframe_To_Production__c = cm.Timeframe_To_Production__c;
                opp.Budget__c = cm.Budget__c;
                opp.User__c = cm.User__c;
                opp.Champion__c = cm.Champion__c;
                opp.Decision_Maker__c = cm.Decision_Maker__c;
                cm.Response_Status__c = 'Qualified - New Opportunity';
                cm.Opportunity_Name__c = opp.Id;
                cm.Opportunity_Create_Date__c = Date.Today();
            }

            else
            {                          
                if(cm.lead.status!=null)
                 {
                    cm.Response_Status__c = cm.lead.status;
                 }
            }
            cm.admin_IsConverted__c = true; 
          }           
        }   

    }

    public static void EmailErrorMessage(String message)
    {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {'edbnotify@bearcavern.com', 'roanbear@gmail.com'});
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('APEX notifier');
        mail.setSubject('SFDC/Eloqua Data Creation Error');
        mail.setPlainTextBody(message);
        List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        for(Messaging.SendEmailResult r: results)
        {
            System.debug('Result of Email sent ' + r.isSuccess());
            if(!r.isSuccess())
            {
                for(Messaging.SendEmailError sme: r.getErrors())
                {
                    for(String s: sme.getFields())  System.Debug('Error for field ' + s );      
                    System.Debug('Error message ' + sme.getMessage());
                    System.Debug('StatusCode ' + sme.getStatusCode());
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

TestClass :

```
@isTest(seealldata=true)
Public class TestCampaignMemberFunctions {

    Public static testMethod void TestCreationDate() {

        Test.StartTest();

        Lead ld2 = [select ID, CreatedDate, IsConverted from LEAD where CreatedDate < :DateTime.Now().addHours(-7) and IsConverted=False  LIMIT 1];
        Campaign cam = new Campaign(Name='campname');      
        insert cam;       
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name ='My Company';
        Insert a;                   

        Lead ld = new Lead();
        ld.Company='colead1';  
        ld.LastName ='colead1_'+String.valueOf(System.now());
        ld.status= 'Junk';        
        ld.admin_CMSourceId__c= cam.Id;              
        insert ld;

        Contact con = new Contact(LastName ='Test');        
        Insert con;               
       // Test.StartTest();
        CampaignMember mc1 = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = cam.Id,Product_Interest__c='Services',Response_Status__c='Disqualified',status= 'Junk', LeadId=ld.Id);
        CampaignMember mc2 = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = cam.Id, LeadId=ld2.Id);
        insert mc1;
        insert mc2; 
        Opportunity opp =new Opportunity();
        opp.Product_Interest__c=mc1.Product_Interest__c;
        opp.Name='Testing';
        opp.StageName='Closed Lost';
        opp.CloseDate=System.today(); 
        Insert opp;       
        CampaignMember mc1res = [Select Id, New_to_EnterpriseDB__c,Response_Status__c from CampaignMember where Id = :mc1.id ];
        CampaignMember mc2res = [Select Id, New_to_EnterpriseDB__c from CampaignMember where Id = :mc2.id ];        
        CampaignMemberFunctions.UpdateNewToEnterpriseDB(mc1,ld);
        System.assert(mc1res.New_to_EnterpriseDB__c);
        System.assert(! mc2res.New_to_EnterpriseDB__c);
        Map<String, CMStatusSettings__c> statusmap = new Map<String, CMStatusSettings__c>();

        Map<Id,Lead> convertedleads = new Map<Id,Lead>();                   
        convertedleads.put(ld.Id,ld);

        Map<Id, Opportunity> convertedops= new Map<Id, Opportunity>();        
        convertedops.put(opp.Id,opp);

        Map<Id, CampaignMember> possiblecms= new Map<Id, CampaignMember>();        
        possiblecms.put(mc1.Id,mc1);                                 
        CampaignMemberFunctions  cmf = new CampaignMemberFunctions();
        CampaignMemberFunctions.SyncStatus( mc1res,ld,con,statusmap);
        System.debug('@@@@@convertedleads'+convertedleads);
        System.debug('@@@@@possiblecms'+possiblecms);
        System.debug('@@@@@convertedops'+convertedops);

        CampaignMemberFunctions.SyncAfterConversion(convertedleads,convertedops,possiblecms);
        CampaignMemberFunctions.EmailErrorMessage('testmessage');     
        Test.StopTest();    
        }              
}
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting the error while running the test?

Comment: @NickSFDC:Yes when i run the test the system throws an error

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for why is falling with the null pointer exception is that either your `Lead` or `CampaingMember` object has not been inserted properly. I would recommend adding some debugging statements like 
`System.debug(ld); System.debug(mc1);` before you're calling `CampaignMemberFunctions.UpdateNewToEnterpriseDB(mc1,ld);`

Comment: :Thanks for your response.As suggested i have added the System.debug in the test  class and checked in debug log where the lead ,campaign ,account and opportunity are getting inserted.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: and does it display as having normal values? if so add the debug statement right before your   if(ld.CreatedDate.addHours(6) > DateTime.Now()) cm.New_to_EnterpriseDB__c = true;  to check again if they maintained consistency. If this works as well but your program fails, add a line such as ld = [Select **** from Lead where id=ld.id]; and same for your mc1 before you make your callout to the other apex class

Comment: :I tried adding the debug stmt but i could not find and debug logs.The other point i didnt get from your end.

Comment: try getting the debug logs first otherwise it's very hard to stop the problem

Comment: :I have added the system.debug in the class as suggested .when checked in debug log ,the class system.debug didnt get display but the system debug which are their in test class gave the output values as it did previous.